# PDFBox hasGlyph() returns true for unsupported unicode control characters

Tags: java, unicode, pdfbox

I'm using Apache's PDFBox library to write a PdfDocumentBuilder class. I'm using `currentFont.hasGlyph(character)` to check if a character has a glyph before attempting to write it to the file. The problem is that when the character is a unicode control character like `'\u001f'`, `hasGlyph()` returns true, causing an exception to be thrown by `encode()` when writing (see PdfDocumentBuilder code and stack trace below for reference).

I did some research and it appears these unicode control characters are not supported for the font I'm using (Courier Prime).

So why does `hasGlyph()` return true for unicode control characters when they are not supported? Of course I could strip the control characters from the line with a simple `replaceAll` before I enter the `writeTextWithSymbol()` method, but if the `hasGlyph()` method isn't working as I expect it to, I have a bigger problem.

PdfDocumentBuilder:

```
private final PDType0Font baseFont;
private PDType0Font currentFont;   

public PdfDocumentBuilder () {
    baseFont = PDType0Font.load(doc, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/CourierPrime.ttf"));
    currentFont = baseFont;
}

private void writeTextWithSymbol (String text) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder nonSymbolBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (char character : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (currentFont.hasGlyph(character)) {
            nonSymbolBuffer.append(character);
        } else {
            //handling writing line with symbols...
        }
    }
    if (nonSymbolBuffer.length() > 0) {
        content.showText(nonSymbolBuffer.toString());
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+001F in font CourierPrime
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:400)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:351)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:316)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:414)
at org.main.export.PdfDocumentBuilder.writeTextWithSymbol(PdfDocumentBuilder.java:193)
```

Comment: What version are you using? The latest is 2.0.4, so please retry with that just to be sure. Does this effect also happen with ordinary fonts like Arial? How did you create the font object?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm using 2.0.4. I've tested with a couple of other standard fonts and the problem still persists. I've added the code that creates the currentFont object.

Comment: I created a simple test and yes it happens with Arial too. I assume that the bug is in hasGlyph, or that the parameter in hasGlyph isn't what one would think. For you, the best would be to call font.encode() with every character and to catch the IllegalArgumentException, to know whether the character is supported or not. This way you'd know for sure. I'll create an issue in JIRA at a later time.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr okay, thank you. I think that's the best option. I dug further and for some reason the value of the character is in the CMap in PDType0Font, but not in the CMapSubtable in PDCIDFontType2, so getGlyphId returns 0, causing the exception.

Comment: I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3708 . If you register in JIRA you can follow any developments. If you want, you can answer the question here yourself with your workaround, so that it helps others, I'm a bit busy and have enough points here :-)

Comment: Update: it's a documentation flaw. The "code" isn't unicode, it's an internal PDF code.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, `hasGlyph()` is not meant to accept unicode characters as a parameter. So if you need to check whether a character can be encoded before writing it, you can do something like this:

```
private void writeTextWithSymbol (String text) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder nonSymbolBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (char character : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (isCharacterEncodeable(character)) {
            nonSymbolBuffer.append(character);
        } else {
            //handle writing line with symbols...
        }
    }
    if (nonSymbolBuffer.length() > 0) {
        content.showText(nonSymbolBuffer.toString());
    }
}

private boolean isCharacterEncodeable (char character) {
    try {
        currentFont.encode(Character.toString(character));
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        LOGGER.trace("Character cannot be encoded", iae);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're catching `IOException` in `isCharacterEncodeable()`. Shouldn't you catch  `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: This is bonkers - to use exceptions to validate each character? Why isn't there a method that just checks.  This is harmful code design.